# How to simplify "There is no A. Also. There is no B."

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to simplify "There is no increasing subsequence of n. Also. There is no decreasing subsequence of length of n."

Which one is correct?

1. Suppose that there are no increasing **or** decreasing subsequences of length n.
2. Suppose that there are no increasing **and** decreasing subsequences of length n.

Comment: "Or" makes sense.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty Yes. More often than not, that's how it would be interpreted.

Comment: @Brody Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should choose or, because and implies that you don't want any subsequences that are both decreasing and increasing. I would probably go with "neither...nor".